# Windows 7 doesn't detect nVidia graphics card

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I am setting up a new PC, I just installed windows 7 but it doesn't detect the card for what it is (nVidia GTX 760) and the device manager in windows only show a generic "Standard VGA adapter".

The nvidia drivers I downloaded say they can't find any supported hardware.

I have installed all the drivers that came with the motherboard (ASRock H170 pro4), but to no avail. The BIOS setup detects the nvidia card on the PCI-E slot, but windows just sees a standard VGA adapter.

I am using the correct card (the monitor is connected to it, not to the builtin motherboard adapter).

The card is ok because I just took it off another PC on which it has been working perfectly since I bought it.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for future reference.

I could get the video drivers to recognize my card and install after a full round of windows update. But that wasn't enough since the most recent nVidia drivers seem to not work well with my GTX 760, and right after boot windows kept telling me that the the "Desktop Window Manager" had stopped working. That meant no aero and quite likely (as I read from many other users) general instability especially in games.

What finally solved the issue was installing an older version of the nVidia drivers (in my case I tried v. 347.52 as someone else with my problem suggested) and everything is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I did a put a new card into my windows 10 machine.  Like you, I tried downloaded drivers or waiting for Windows to correctly identify it with multiple reboots but in the end, I had to use the driver disk that came with the card.  For some reason, the physical install program worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2725903/graphics-card-drivers-install-card-detected-system.html#16306858), Windows gets confused, installs a bad driver and pretends it's the best thing ever. Someone I know solved his problem the following way:

1. Use http://www.processblocker.com/ to block drvinst.exe in C:\Windows\System32 from running.

   - [Alternatively](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/install/enabling-support-for-debugging-device-installations), temporarily setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Device Installer\DebugInstall` to `2` should have the same effect (it still runs but just waits for a debugger).
2. Uninstall the Standard VGA Adapter from Device Manager.
3. (Reboot), installing NVidia drivers should work fine now.
4. Revert the blocking/regedit on drvinst.exe

Answer (score 0):

This is a service to the community. I had the same problem for months with a Dell Latitude D830 and a Nvidia NVS 110M graphics card after upgrading to Windows 7 64 bit. I installed all the possible drivers both from Nvidia and from Dell and I always got either a non-compatible device, either a conflict between 32 and 64 bit versions (even when installing 64 bit drivers). I tried every solution on the net and nothing worked. I even installed poor quality driver seeker software that didn't solve the problem and installed unwanted software in my computer.

I was about to reinstall Vista, and then I found the solution: it's called [Snappy Driver Installer](https://www.lifewire.com/snappy-driver-installer-review-2619199). It's free, 0 unwanted software (it's standalone), it's community-built (thank you community!) and it does the trick. It's not friendly and I had to download 2 GB of driver databases until it found and installed the right one for my graphics card. I am back with full resolution and able to connect and external monitor. I hope this helps someone not to sped months loosing time on this issue.